# Dump Emails from Exchange 2003 that match Certain Criteria

Tags: exchange-2003

Is it possible to retrieve emails that would match the following from Exchange 2003:

(Sent OR Recieved from a list of users) & ( Contains keyword x OR y OR z) & (Between x and y date)

and then send them to a new account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Exmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=429163ec-dcdf-47dc-96da-1c12d67327d5&displaylang=en) to extract data from Exchange 2003 that meets certain criteria, which can include dates, subjects and attachments, which may get your some of the way there. It won't let you filter by sent or received from though.

You could use exmerge to get emails with the right subject and date out, and then open this with outlook and use outlook to filter based on the recipient.

As this is a PST file you can open it as an additional PST in outlook and drag and drop messages into your Exchange account, or other mailboxes.

Comment: Was looking at that, would I then be able to import the results of that search into an account?

Comment: Exmerge writes out to a PST file. So you should be able to set that up for either direct access (the term escapes me right now) or import it into a users account in using outlook.

Comment: As Kyle said, exmerge outputs to a pst so you can access this with your favourite mail software. In outlook you can either use it as the default mail store, or open it as an additional pst and then move messages between pst adn your mailbox.